# xcode4 analyze shows a line i'm not sure how to fix

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] autorelease];
mdict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

return mdict; // on this line, analyze says "Value stored to mdict during it's initializtion is never read"
```

Any ideas how to **fix** this so that I can successfully *analyze* my project with xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first line of code, you are creating allocating memory for a mutable dictionary.  The second line you are creating another NSMutableDictionary, thereby leaving the one created in the first line as a leak.  The solution is to remove the first line and modify the second one as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: I'm kind of embarrassed I didn't see that. That's what I get when it's EOD I suppose.

Comment: No worries.  The code all looks the same this late in the day.

Answer (score 2):

On the second line the assignment to `mdict` replaces the initialization on the first line.  Thus the instance created on the first line is never used.

What you want is something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually talking about the return line, its talking about the first line.  to fix it, just use `NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`